# Adding colour to the output of a bash command?

Tags: bash, color

I'm working with pytest and have keybindings set up to run all the tests in the specific file I'm working on. The command I run is:

`:! pytest -vs "<C-r>%"`

However, the output of this bash command has no colour! Is it possible to have the coloured output you would get in a regular terminal inside the bash command output of neovim? I'd rather not run `:term` if possible.

I can add images if required.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `--color=yes`, as per `$ pytest --help`?

Comment: I just did and i got an output like this: `^[[32mPASSED^[[0m`. I'm assuming the nvim output can't represent the colours implied by those symbols.

Comment: Yes. I know you said that you don't want `:term` but it would work better.

Comment: would it be possible to pipe a command into the `:term` and have it run automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, I figured out a workaround.

First, you need a command to split a `:term` into a regular split:

`command! -nargs=* T split | terminal <args>`

You can change this to a vsplit if you'd like.

Now, you can update your test shortcut to use that command:

`autocmd FileType python nnoremap <leader>test :w<CR>:T pytest -vs "<C-r>%"<CR>`

This works for me, and the terminal that opened can be closed with `:q`.

Comment: This must be NeoVim specific, because in Vim `:terminal` does split automatically.